# What should i export to resolve this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-redux

```
// Code in index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the error message:

> Error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's
> defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you also showed a minimal version of your current App.js

Comment: also pls add your package.json because sometimes the error comes from version

Comment: Also, what line / component is that error triggered on? I'd think that happens on the App component, so please share the code of that file too

Comment: Seeing as how there's only 1 component import here, `App`, and it's a default import, I guess you should update it to be a named import. Seeing how you define and export `App` from "./App" should validate this. Maybe you ***did*** forget to export it at all.